# Using variable in SQL Query Builder Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview, query-builder

I am working with datagridview and what i want to accomplish is to `select column from table where column = expression`.
Problem is that i do not know how to use query builder and do not know if that is possible there. I want my expression to pull from combobox.SelectedValue. In normal code i would go like

`"SELECT column2, column3 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = " + (int)combobox.SelectedValue + ""` but how to write this in query builder?
How to get value of SelectedValue in query builder so i can use it in WHERE

Answer (score -1):

Try this, one mistake you are making is casting the combobox value to int when the value should be string, regardless the best way to pass parameters to SQL queries is as below.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE someColumn = @comboboxparam";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    var comboBoxParam = new SqlParameter("someColumn", SqlDbType.Text);
    comboBoxParam.Value = comboBox.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(comboBoxParam);
    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: i know that, but how to do that in sql query in visual studio

Comment: As above, just modify the example to suite your need.